# Java: two method signatures with same number of arguments

Tags: java, generics, dictionary, set

I am implementing a special type of Set/Map class.
I want the following two methods:

```
public boolean addAll(Map<K,Integer> map)
public boolean addAll(Iterable<E> elements)
```

This works fine as intended.

However if someone makes a class which implements both Iterable and Map I will get into trouble.

What I would want is

```
public<T extends Map<K, Integer> & Iterable<K>> boolean addAll(T itermap)
```

However java tells me there are two methods with same erasure.

I see two poor fixes:

1) make two methods with different name

2) Make a joint method as follows

```
public addAll(Object obj)
    if(obj instanceof Map && obj instanceof Iterable)
        ....
    else if(obj instanceof Iterable)
        ...
    else if(obj instanceof Map)
        ...         
}
```

This last one is ugly since there is all kind of exceptions to be thrown (objects not implementing either, maps with wrong generics and so on.

Is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Why do you say you'd get into trouble? The compiler will pick the appropriate overload to call based on the static type of the argument, and if someone wants to call your method with a class that implements both then it's up to them to add an appropriate cast.

Comment: Maps are not iterable. Why worry about someone implementing both interfaces on a class? If they are silly enough to do that, let them cast it as they wish - don't pollute your API based on what-ifs

Comment: I agree that Maps should not be iterable in general since one does not know whether to iterate over keys or values, however one possible extension of a map is to implement a permutation, hence the keys and the values are the same set and it would make sense to have it as an iterable.

The point here is that in general one may want to take different actions depending on whether one of two interfaces are implemented or if both of the interfaces are implemented.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1:

Specify the method you want to use with a cast (let `iterableMap` be the object that should be the parameter for the function and `mySpecialSetMap` a instance of your special class):

```
mySpecialSetMap.addAll((Map<K, Integer>) iterableMap);
```

or

```
mySpecialSetMap.addAll((Iterable<K>) iterableMap);
```

#### Solution 2:

Create a new interface that extends `Map<K, Integer>` and `Iterable<K>`:

```
interface IterableMap<K> extends Map<K, Integer>, Iterable<K> {

}
```

And implement this interface in the class that extends `Map<K, Integer>` and `Iterable<K>`.

---

Solution 2 is more elegant, but maybe you cannot use it, e.g. because the "someone" doesn't want to implement the interface.

Comment: I agree Solution 2 is more elegant but I also think it would add extra complexity to the calling class. Casting is not very user friendly either, especially to explain in the documentation that one need to cast but it does not matter which of the two you cast to.

I don't see why Java could not have checked if one method signature requires a subset of the interfaces another signature requires and if so choose the maximal match (as long as the maximal is unique)